# Same image displaying differently in different browsers

Tags: image, browser, jpeg

Here is an image:

[image]

When I load this image in different browsers, it shows differently.
Take a look at the result:

[image]

I spent a lot of time on this, but I can't understand why it happens.
I have only theories: something wrong with color profiles, or bad image structure, or something else - maybe special copyright measures?

Why is this happening?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The image is a CMYK image, which IE and Safari apparently do not support. Converting it into an RGB image solved the problem for both Safari and IE.

RGB Version:

[image: RGB version]

The color's been changed though, so you'd probably want to run it through Photoshop and edit the color balance to get the colors right.

Comment: Thank you. I heard about CMYK, but never imagined that it could cause the problems at the web-sites.

Comment: @Vickodin At Stack Overflow, if an answer answers your question, then you should mark it as such, using the green checkmark on the side of each answer. This marks your question as resolved and gives both the answerer and the asker a small reward for doing so.

Comment: @Yi Jiang Thanks for explanations. Done.

Answer (score 0):

There could be something wrong with the image. Open it in some image editor like GIMP and check if it gives some warnings. Try converting the image to some other format(png?) and see if the browsers render it correctly.

Comment: Answered, see the top. Thanks.